# Deregistering a script in Wordpress seems impossible

Tags: php, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-script

I tried everything. I even removed all content in functions.php and created a whole new file with just this:

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
 if (is_singular()) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'gdrts-rating' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

The idea is to remove some Javascript files from my custom post type. I thought I was doing something wrong so I first tried with is_page() and even is_home(), but even that is not working for me. It seems like the code is not fired or so.

**This is my plugin:**

```
  wp_enqueue_script('gdrts-events', $this->file('js', 'events'), array(), gdrts_settings()->file_version(), false);
    wp_enqueue_script('gdrts-rating', $this->file('js', 'rating'), $depend_js, gdrts_settings()->file_version(), true);
```

So, I also tried to do it like this:

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'gdrts-rating' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Not working!

Comment: Can you indent your code? Also why are you trying to deregister a script? Are you sure it's deregistering you want not dequeing?

Comment: I want to remove it from the DOM... so I don't want it to be loaded on specific pages.

Comment: Registering a script doesn't put it in the dom. Enquing it is what puts it in the DOM. You don't want to deregister, you want to dequeue. Also if you use the body class properly then you can make sure your styles don't apply to those pages even if they do get loaded. The same with your scripts

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you meant with the body class. You mean for the styling, right? If so, what exactly do you mean?

Honestly, my main pain is with scripts (Javascript). Trying to optimise the pages for speed.... but I have the same issue with dequeuing. My code is not working. See also edited question.

Comment: you can just take any answer on how to load scripts on on page X and swap the enqueue for a dequeue

Comment: That does not work for me - that is my problem. I even tried a clean functions.php, but it seems like the code is not firing.

Comment: See also updated question. I have showed even how the plugin works... I can't get it to work.

Comment: Uhhhm, just a sidenote while reading it. You do know that functions.php is for themes automatically loaded? Not for plugins. You have to include that in your plugin file with require or something else.

Comment: That does not make sense. What if the plugin is being updated? Then all my code is gone. The place for this, is the functions.php. That's what I know.

Answer (score 1):

Try `deregister_script` in addition to `dequeue_script`

```
function wpdocs_dequeue_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'gdrts-rating' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'gdrts-rating' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note the below is done via a custom plugin and not in the functions file as most themes when updated will overwrite the functions file.

The below is tested and works to unqueue a script, I have added code that you can use to test if the file is loaded prior to removing it and also I would use your custom post name if you only wish this to be unloaded on that post type in is_singular().

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Remove_script_Stack_353322
Plugin URI: www.mywebsite.com
Description: Remove a script when needed
Version: 1.0
Author: Me
Author URI: www.mywebsite.com
*/

    /**
     * Enqueue script.
     */
    function my_scripts_method() {
        //Change your plugin url/name
        wp_enqueue_script( 'gdrts-rating', plugins_url( 'test.js' , __FILE__ ));
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );



    function wpdocs_dequeue_script() 
    {

        // Lets check if gdrts-rating is loaded
        $handle = 'gdrts-rating';
        $list = 'enqueued';
        if (wp_script_is( $handle, $list )) 
        {

            //echo 'Loaded --------------------------------------------------------------------->';
            // Custom post type so use the name in ->  is_singular('custom_post_name')  you can have more post types such as is_singular('custom_post_name', 'custom_post_2')

            if (is_singular()) 
            {
             // Unload the plugin
             wp_dequeue_script( 'gdrts-rating' );
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
           // Not loaded do nothing
           //echo 'Not loaded --------------------------------------------------------------------->';
        }


    }
    add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpdocs_dequeue_script', 10 );
```